# How to use vim's 'f' command (find) to find the next tab

Tags: search, vim, find

I use vim's f command all the time, but I can't figure out how to find special characters (like tabs).  E.g., hitting `f\t` searches for `\`.  I know you can use digraphs in conjunction with the `f` command, but I don't think there is a digraph for the tab character.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just type <kbd>f</kbd> and then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Wow - what a dumb question in retrospect!  I guess I assumed that wouldn't work for some reason.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For historical and technical reasons, `<C-i>` is the same as `<Tab>` so you can use `f<C-i>`.